# What is the significance of silver colored vehicles in The Host (2013)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-host

What is the significance of silver colored vehicles in *The Host (2013)*?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Product Placement.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement)

> Product placement, Placement Promotion or embedded marketing, is
>   according to Business Dictionary, "an advertising technique used by
>   companies to subtly promote their products through a non-traditional
>   advertising technique, usually through appearances in film,
>   television, or other media."

The car featured is a [Lotus Evora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Evora):
[image: This is an S400 model from 2014.]

And Lotus Cars wasn't shy about it either:

[Lotus Returns to the Big Screen](http://www.lotuscars.com/news/corporate/lotus-returns-big-screen):

> The long awaited movie adaptation of ‘The Host’ written by Stephanie
>   Myer, author of ‘The Twilight Saga’ premiered in LA on 19th March and
>   will be on international release from March 22nd at which time big
>   screens all over the world will be alight with a fleet of awesome
>   looking Lotus Evoras.

The motorcycle is an [Aprilia_RSV4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprilia_RSV4):
[image]

> Max Biaggi ended his career winning the 2012 title with the RSV4.
>
> The Aprilia RSV4 is available as a customer-specified race bike from
>   the factory as a Max Biaggi replica.
>
> Sylvain Guintoli won the 2014 Superbike World Championship season
>   riding an RSV4 for the factory Aprilia racing team.

And to conclude:

[Ride Apart describes the Superbikes' appearance in The Host.](https://rideapart.com/articles/suspend-your-disbelief-the-host)

Comment: As far as why the vehicles are all *silver* (because I'm sure they could have been made available in any colour the production team requested), it's probably just because nothing says "this is the future" better than shiny, sleek silver vehicles.